# How to test onPress for an Icon in React Native using Jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-test-renderer

In my program, I have a touchable icon that that sets a password field from hidden to visible, I need to test that when the icon is pressed, the password becomes visible. I have tried the following:

```
wrapper.find({name:"icon"}).first().props().onPress();
```

However, I get the error message:

```
Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Icon to press, you should try like this:

```
wrapper.find(Icon).first().props().onPress();
```

or

```
wrapper.find(icon).first().props().onPress();
```

Use Button works like:

```
wrapper.find(Button).first().props().onPress();
```

Put the Tag what you used.